Issue connecting to Docker daemon in development environment (free Render version)
I've developed a Java application with Spring Boot that utilizes Docker to run Python scripts within containers. My development environment is working fine, but I'm encountering an issue when attempting to deploy my application to production on Render.
Here's the error I'm facing:

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Additional Details:
I'm using Docker version 20.10.7, installed on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine.
My Spring Boot application is built with Java 17.
I've configured my Dockerfile to install Docker, Java, Python, and other necessary dependencies.
I'm using Docker Compose to orchestrate my application along with a PostgreSQL service.
In my Docker Compose file, I've mounted the /var/run/docker.sock volume to allow my application to interact with the host's Docker daemon.
I should note that I'm restricted to using the free version of Docker due to budget constraints.
Despite these attempts, the issue persists. How can I resolve this problem of connecting to the Docker daemon in my development environment?
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    image: code_stream_backend:tag
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - spring.datasource.url=
      - spring.datasource.username=
      - spring.datasource.password=
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./data:/data

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: monmotdepasse
      POSTGRES_DB: votre_base_de_donnees
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common

RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add - && \
    add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable" && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-17-jdk

RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip

RUN apt-get install -y curl wget vim

RUN mkdir /data

WORKDIR /app

COPY target/CodeStream-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/app.jar

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]


Your image already contains Python, it looks like; can you just run Python as a subprocess?  This will be much easier to set up and avoids some significant security concerns.

@DavidMaze, thank you for the suggestion. However, running Python scripts directly as subprocesses within the same container as my application poses significant security risks. It's generally advised to isolate execution environments, especially for potentially untrusted scripts, to minimize the impact of security vulnerabilities and ensure better resource management. Docker containers provide a robust mechanism for isolating applications and their dependencies, which is why I opted for that approach initially.

You can't create a Docker container without a dependency on the Docker API (this will be hard to run in other container environments), and that generally implies unrestricted root-level access over the entire system.  Docker is not going to be a good way to run truly untrusted scripts (they can still attempt to attack the host OS kernel, and you'll be better off running the cryptocurrency miners yourself).
